# Method of moments estimator question given PDF

Tags: density-function, parameter-estimation, moment-problem

I'm having a little trouble with this question which I got from my statistics tutorial.

If $Y_1, Y_2, ..., Y_n$ is a random sample from a population **Y** having a probability density function given by:

$$f(y : \alpha, \beta) =  
\begin{cases}
\alpha\beta^\alpha y^{-(\alpha + 1)},  & \text{if $y$ $\gt$ $\beta$} \\
0, & \text{$otherwise$}
\end{cases}$$

where $\alpha \gt 0$ and $\beta$ is assumed to be known. Then, a method of moments estimator for $\alpha$ is given by:

**a)** $\widehat \alpha$ $=$ $\frac{M_1}{(M_1 - \beta)}$, where $M_1 = \frac {1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i $

**b)** $\widehat \alpha$ $=$ $\frac{M_1}{(\beta - M_1)}$, where $M_1 = \frac {1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i $

**c)** $\widehat \alpha$ $=$ $\frac{2M_2}{(M_2 + \beta^2)}$, where $M_2 = \frac {1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i^2 $

**d)** None of the above

My attempt: I've tried referring to my lecture notes but I'm not quite sure how to attempt this question.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome to math.SE, since you appear to be new I wanted to give you a
couple of tips. First of, it is usually helpful to say in what context
this problem was found, and more importantly which are your
thoughts. Second, some of us consider imperative expressions such as
"show'', "prove'', "evaluate'' ... somewhat rude, try to be
polite. And finally, perhaps related with the first point, this is not
a site for solving homework, please consider this and try to rephrase
your question

Comment: Oh I'm really sorry for that. I will edit it. Thank you for the heads up

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the first moment of the distribution

$$
\mathbb{E}[Y] = \int_{0}^{+\infty}{\rm d}y~yf(y;\alpha,\beta) = \alpha\beta^{\alpha}\int_{\beta}^{+\infty}{\rm dy}~y^{-\alpha} = \frac{\alpha\beta}{\alpha - 1}, ~~~\alpha>1
$$

The method of moments relies on the assumption

$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^ny_i = M_1 = \mathbb{E}[Y] = \frac{\alpha\beta}{\alpha - 1}
$$

From this you can get $\alpha$

$$
\hat{\alpha} = \frac{M_1}{M_1 - \beta }
$$